# UnityMobilePaint not working on actual device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, drawing

I'm using https://github.com/unitycoder/UnityMobilePaint library for drawing in unity
I have imported one scene from this to my unity project
its working fine on unity editor but not woking when running on actual android device
for android device MobilePaint.cs file line no 532

```
if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, paintLayerMask)) { wentOutside = true; return; }
```

always return false
for editor return true

Comment: You should edit your question to provide more information. Please write the whole message of the exception. 


Anyway this kind of exceptions is difficult to parse over the internet, because it can be device dependend. Not many people are willing to download any kind of library, build the project and test it on their devices to repply the question. So you have to install logcat.  You can find a lot of videos about that on Youtube easily: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Logcat+unity

It would be much easier to fix this problem with virtual android machine Blue Stacks or Nox.